# Constructing graph from geometries and tieing points to graph after graph creation using PyQGIS network analysis

Tags: pyqgis, network-analysis

I am solving some Euclidean shortest path problems, thus I create my lines/arcs myself. Following code from PyQGIS cookbook I need to import a vector layer to start building a graph:

```
vl = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(vl, -1, '', '', '', 3)
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter(properter)
crs = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)
pStart = QgsPoint(-0.743804, 0.22954)
tiedPoint = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart])
```

As far as I understand the code the director is the one actually initializing the graph and according to the API documentation there is no other way to do so. I was wondering if this is correct or if I miss something. (It would be kind of cumbersome to first create a layer to then load it, if I already have all geometries.)

Also as far as I understand it I can only tie points to the graph while initializing it with the director. This would be pretty expensive, if the start/end points are variable depending on my Euclidean shortest path end point (I want to start a normal shortest path analysis from the end point of the Euclidean shortest path with an end point on a line).

Do I miss something?

I found `QgsGraphBuilder().addEdge/Vertex` and `QgsGraph().addEdge/Vertex` but am quite unsure what they exactly do (and if they are able to do what I want) and what input they expect.

I am using QGIS 2.8.1.

Comment: For a network analysis example without director and properter check https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/blob/master/qgis2/scripts/ogd/idf_router.py